# Orbits are the minimal $G$-invariant subsets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

A subset $\phi \subseteq \Omega $ is G-invariant ($G \le$ Sym$(\Omega)$ ) if $(\forall \sigma \in G)(\phi^\sigma = \phi)$. The orbits of the action are the equivalence classes of the relation $\Omega$ defined as " $x \equiv_G y$" if $(\exists\sigma \in G)(x^\sigma = y)$.

**My Question :** Orbits are the minimal $G$-invariant subsets. I know that orbits are the partitions of the set $\Omega$ but not able to prove that "Orbits are the minimal $G$-invariant subsets".

Comment: Let O be an orbit. Let H be a proper subset of O. Can you prove that H is not G-invariant?

Comment: @ CoffeeBliss. This is exactly what I want to prove.

Comment: There exists an $x \in O-H$. If $H$ is $G$-invariant, that means that for every $g \in G$ and $h \in H$, $h^g$ is an element $\textit{in}$ $H$. Can you get a contradiction somehow? Think about the definition of orbit.

Comment: @CoffeeBliss Then there will be no element $\sigma$ of $G$ such that $x^{\sigma} = y$

Comment: What are your $x$ and $y$?

Comment: $x$ is same as above you have defined and $y \in H$ (because H is $G$-invariant). So contradiction to assumption that $H$ is a Orbit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60973/discussion-between-isla-bonita-and-coffeebliss).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about it like this. What's an orbit? $G$ is some random group that acts on some set $\Omega$. Take any element $x$ in $\Omega$. Every element $g$ of $G$ sends $x$ to some other element of $\Omega$ -- call that point $gx$. The set of elements of the form $gx$ is called the orbit of $x$. It's just what you get when you take every element of $G$ and see where it sends $x$. Any orbit is $G$-invariant. Furthermore, it is a minimal $G$-invariant set because if you took some proper subset of it, you're "missing" some of the points that $x$ gets sent to. In the hint above I gave a suggestion as to how to give a proof.

Here's a proof. Let $O$ be an orbit of $G$. Let $x \in O$. Then $O=Gx$. We claim that $O$ is a minimal $G$-invariant subset. Let $H$ be a proper subset of $O$. We will show that $H$ is not $G$-invariant. Let $y$ be such that $y \in O$ but $y \notin H$. Then $y = gx$ for some $g \in G$. We claim that there exists an element $x' \in H$ such that for some $g' \in G,$ $g'x' \notin H$. In fact, we can take $x'$ to be any element $h \in H$. Then $h$ has the form $g''x$ for some $g \in G$. Then $g(g'')^{-1}h=gx=y$, which is not in $H$. Therefore $H$ is not invariant under $G$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $G$ acts on $X$ and $x$ an element of $X$, let $Y$ a subset of the orbit of $x$ which is invariant by $G$, let $y\in Y$, $y=g.x$ implies $x=g^{-1}.y$ we deduce $x\in Y$ and $Y=X$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ does not act on $\mathbb{Z}/6$ by multiplication. The identity in $\mathbb{Z}$ is 0, so 0 would have to fix each element in $\mathbb{Z}/6$.

Comment: Why can't $Y$ be empty?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a roadmap:

- An orbit is a $G$-invariant subset
- A $G$-invariant subset is a union of orbits
- If a $G$-invariant subset contains more than one orbit, then it is not minimal.
- A minimal $G$-invariant subset is an orbit